# Composite community event calendar and form renderer

Tags: c1-cms

After having followed the C1 setup guidance regarding the event calendar and form renderer - the resulting event entries are cramped on one line and there is no link to the std. sign-up.
Maybe take a look at FairNets.dk / events.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot somewhere describing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ~/App_Data/PageTemplates/MasterLayout.cshtml file and add a xml namespace to the root element:

From:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

That should solve the problem